# What is the purpose of classmethod in this code?

Tags: python

In django.utils.tree.py:

```
def _new_instance(cls, children=None, connector=None, negated=False):
    obj = Node(children, connector, negated)
    obj.__class__ = cls
    return obj
_new_instance = classmethod(_new_instance)
```

I don't know what `classmethod` does in this code sample. Can someone explain what it does and how to use it?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

`classmethod` is a decorator, wrapping a function, and you can call the resulting object on a class or (equivalently) an instance thereof:

```
>>> class x(object):
...   def c1(*args): print 'c1', args
...   c1 = classmethod(c1)
...   @classmethod
...   def c2(*args): print 'c2', args
... 
>>> inst = x()
>>> x.c1()
c1 (<class '__main__.x'>,)
>>> x.c2()
c2 (<class '__main__.x'>,)
>>> inst.c1()
c1 (<class '__main__.x'>,)
>>> inst.c2()
c2 (<class '__main__.x'>,)
```

As you see, whether you define it directly or with decorator syntax, and whether you call it on the class or the instance, the `classmethod` always receives the class as its first argument.

One of the main uses of classmethod is to define *alternative constructors*:

```
>>> class y(object):
...   def __init__(self, astring):
...     self.s = astring
...   @classmethod
...   def fromlist(cls, alist):
...     x = cls('')
...     x.s = ','.join(str(s) for s in alist)
...     return x
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'y(%r)' % self.s
...
>>> y1 = y('xx')
>>> y1
y('xx')
>>> y2 = y.fromlist(range(3))
>>> y2
y('0,1,2')
```

Now if you subclass `y`, the classmethod keeps working, e.g.:

```
>>> class k(y):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'k(%r)' % self.s.upper()
...
>>> k1 = k.fromlist(['za','bu'])
>>> k1
k('ZA,BU')
```

Comment: This isn't an altenative constructor, this is a factory method.

Comment: @t3chb0t it is a factory method that works as an alternative constructor.

Comment: Agreed with @t3chb0t, this is an alternative [string representation of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). Objects of class y and k in this example appear to have the same construction.

Answer (score 9):

It makes it possible to call the method on the class instead of an object:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def _new_instance(cls, blah):
        pass
    _new_instance = classmethod(_new_instance)

MyClass._new_instance("blah")
```

Comment: It's also more commonly used as a decorator: `@classmethod def _new_instance(cls, blah):`